# How to use Facebook messenger dialog in react native?

Tags: facebook, react-native, facebook-messenger, react-native-fbsdk

I am using react-native-fbsdk to use Facebook APIs in my react native project. I am able to implement login/share/logout functionalities using this but till now haven't found any way to use Facebook messenger send dialog. 
Is there any way I can integrate FB messenger send dialog in a react native project using this?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this opens the messenger send dialog (at least on iOS):

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
  MessageDialog
} = FBSDK; 
........
........
........
const shareLinkContent = {
  contentType: 'link',
  contentUrl: 'http://xxxx',
  //contentDescription: 'DONT USE ITS AGAINST FB POLICY',
};

MessageDialog.canShow(shareLinkContent).then(
  function(canShow) {
      if (canShow) {
        return MessageDialog.show(shareLinkContent);
      } else {
        alert('Messenger not installed')
      }
    }
  ).then(
    function(result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        // cancelled
      } else {
        // success
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      showToast('Share fail with error: ' + error, 'error');
    }
  );
```

Hope it helps you!